# How to loop through Dictionary Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I've this dictionary :

```
var proposals: [[Character: String]] = [[Character: String]]()
```

How i properly loop it to retrieve both values ?

Comment: Solution in target post doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop through the top array to get dictionaries, then loop through dictionaries.

```
for subArray in proposals {
    for (key,value) in subArray {
        print("\(key) == \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it work fine :)